# How can one manage to fully use the newly enhanced Parallelism features in .NET 4.0?

Tags: multithreading, .net-4.0, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, plinq

I am pretty much interested into using the newly enhanced Parallelism features in .NET 4.0.

I have also seen some possibilities of using it in F#, as much as in C#.

Despite, I can only see what PLINQ has to offer with, for example, the following:

```
var query = from c in Customers.AsParallel()
            where (c.Name.Contains("customerNameLike"))
            select c;
```

There must for sure be some other use of this parallelism thing.

Have you any other examples of using it? Is this particularly turned toward PLINQ, or are there other usage as easy as PLINQ?

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new parallel programming features provided in .NET 4 are not limited to just PLINQ.

As stated by Microsoft: "*Visual Studio 2010 and the .NET Framework 4 enhance support for parallel programming by providing a new runtime, new class library types, and new diagnostic tools. These features simplify parallel development so that you can write efficient, fine-grained, and scalable parallel code in a natural idiom without having to work directly with threads or the thread pool.*"

I would recommend that you review [Parallel Programming in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460693(VS.100).aspx) as a good starting place.

Overall, .NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010 provide these features:

- [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=VS.100).aspx)
- [Parallel LINQ (PLINQ)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688(v=VS.100).aspx)
- [Data Structures for Parallel
  Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460718(v=VS.100).aspx)
- [Parallel Diagnostic Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460685(v=VS.100).aspx)
- Overall improvements to the
  ThreadPool and the base class
  libraries

I personally have found the Task and Task{T} classes in the Task Parallel Library to be more flexible when creating and coordinating asynchronous work.

Comment: There are multiple examples at the teams blog http://blogs.msdn.com/pfxteam there are also a ton of samples available at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples.

Answer (score 2):

My team has also just finished a book on this...

***Parallel Programming with Microsoft® .NET:*** 
*Design Patterns for Decomposition and Coordination on Multicore Architectures*

Colin Campbell, Ralph Johnson, Ade Miller and Stephen Toub. Foreword by Tony Hey

You can download a draft and samples here: http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/

The full book will be available on MSDN later this month and on Amazon in October.

Apologies for the blatant plug but I think you might find the content really helpful.

**Update...**

To answer your question (below) the problem you picked, an implementation of an Aggregation (from a list create an aggregate based on the list content) happens to map far better to PLinq than the alternative, Parallel.ForEach. There's an example of aggregation with Parallel.ForEach on p72 of the PDF.

If you simply want to update the contents of a set using PLinq the mapping is much simpler. For example the following code loops over a list of accounts, calculates a balance trend and flags accounts with predicted balances more than their overdraft limit.

Sequential:

```
static void UpdatePredictionsSequential(AccountRepository accounts)
{
    foreach (Account account in accounts.AllAccounts)
    {
        Trend trend = SampleUtilities.Fit(account.Balance);
        double prediction = trend.Predict(account.Balance.Length + NumberOfMonths); 
        account.SeqPrediction = prediction;
        account.SeqWarning = prediction < account.Overdraft;
    }
}
```

PLinq:

```
static void UpdatePredictionsPlinq(AccountRepository accounts)
{            
    accounts.AllAccounts
        .AsParallel()
        .ForAll(account =>
            {
                Trend trend = SampleUtilities.Fit(account.Balance);
                double prediction = trend.Predict(account.Balance.Length + NumberOfMonths);
                account.PlinqPrediction = prediction;
                account.PlinqWarning = prediction < account.Overdraft;         
            });
}
```

Parallel.ForEach:

```
static void UpdatePredictionsParallel(AccountRepository accounts)
{
    Parallel.ForEach(accounts.AllAccounts, account =>
    {
        Trend trend = SampleUtilities.Fit(account.Balance);
        double prediction = trend.Predict(account.Balance.Length + NumberOfMonths);
        account.ParPrediction = prediction;
        account.ParWarning = prediction < account.Overdraft;
    });
}
```

In some cases, PLinq may be the most expressive choice. In others Parallel.For/ForEach may be better, in some cases it's largly a matter of programmer preference.

However, the Task Parallel Library supports more that the Parallel Loop and Aggregation patterns. It allows you to construct tasks that will be scheduled for parallel execution on multicore hardware (Task Parallelism pattern):

```
static int ParallelTaskImageProcessing(Bitmap source1, Bitmap source2,
                                    Bitmap layer1, Bitmap layer2, Graphics blender)
{
    Task toGray = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SetToGray(source1, layer1));
    Task rotate = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Rotate(source2, layer2));
    Task.WaitAll(toGray, rotate);
    Blend(layer1, layer2, blender);
    return source1.Width;
}
```

It allows you to create graphs of tasks where the output of one task is fed into another (Task Graph or Futures  pattern):

```
public static int Example4()
{
    var a = 22;

    var cf = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => F2(a));
    var df = cf.ContinueWith((t) => F3(t.Result));
    var b = F1(a);
    var f = F4(b, df.Result);
    return f;
}
```

Where F1-F4 are functions who's inputs and outputs have dependencies.

It supports creating trees of dependent tasks, for Divide and Conquer problems like sorting (the Dynamic Task Parallelism pattern):

```
static void ParallelWalk<T>(Tree<T> tree, Action<T> action)
{
    if (tree == null) return;
    var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
               () => action(tree.Data));
    var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
               () => ParallelWalk(tree.Left, action));
    var t3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(
               () => ParallelWalk(tree.Right, action));
    Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);
}
```

It also implements several (threadsafe) collections for use in a parallel program. Which allows straightforward implementation of, for example, the Pipeline pattern:

```
static void Chapter7Example01Pipeline(int seed)
{
    Console.Write("Begin Pipelined Sentence Builder");

    var buffer1 = new BlockingCollection<string>(BufferSize);
    var buffer2 = new BlockingCollection<string>(BufferSize);
    var buffer3 = new BlockingCollection<string>(BufferSize);

    var f = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
                            TaskContinuationOptions.None);

    var stage1 = f.StartNew(() => ReadStrings(buffer1, seed));
    var stage2 = f.StartNew(() => CorrectCase(buffer1, buffer2));
    var stage3 = f.StartNew(() => CreateSentences(buffer2, buffer3));
    var stage4 = f.StartNew(() => WriteSentences(buffer3));

    Task.WaitAll(stage1, stage2, stage3, stage4);
}
```

All of the above features also contain support for exception handling and cancellation, although for clarity I've not shown them here.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. =) Besides, could you post a simple code sample to show address another way than PLINQ? Thanks! =)

Comment: Will, I updated my answer with a lot more detail. It just so happens your particular example maps best to PLinq.

Comment: Thank you for this update. My example is suitable for PLINQ as this is what has gained my attention the most, and this is also the most used instance to explain the possibility of parallelism. Your examples are great! I already upvoted, but I would like to upvote your answer again. And it's a shame that I can't accept two answers as the solution to my question. Besides, I shall study your examples to get acquainted with parallelism in .NET 4.0. I also shall download the sample of your book and see if this could be a good reference for me to use. Thanks Ade!

Answer (score 1):

Watch [this Scott Hanselman presentation](http://www.ditii.com/2010/04/16/touring-net-4-framework-with-scott-hanselman/) from 39:30 to 48:36.  (Starting at 39 minutes, 30 seconds into the talk).